# Exception when running newly created Cordova2 Project in Xcode Simulator

Tags: iphone, xcode, cordova-2.0.0

I created a new Cordova2 Project for Xcode like it is described in their "Getting started" Guide. Everything is build without any problems but after Starting the iPhone Simulator, the App pops up and then Xcode brings me to the main.m in "Other sources" and highlights this line:

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegate");
```

It says: Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

When I step over this (actually I have to step over it twice for some reason) I get the following Exception in the log and the App in the Simulator closes (and is unstartable afterwards):

```
2012-08-30 11:27:33.807 test2[8198:13403] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 

'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIApplication 0x9039420> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.'

*** First throw call stack:
(0x1a1022 0x207ccd6 0x1a0ee1 0xf04022 0xe75f6b 0xe75edb 0xe90d50 0x55a71a 0x1a2dea 0x10c7f1 0x55926e 0x55aeb7 0x337ce1 0x337ff8 0x33717f 0x346183 0x346c38 0x33a634 0x271eef5 0x175195 0xd9ff2 0xd88da 0xd7d84 0xd7c9b 0x336c65 0x338626 0x2716 0x2685)
terminate called throwing an exception
```

Could anyone help me with this? If you need further info, please ask me.